# Java: Print table of data

Tags: java, javafx, printing

I want to be able to print a list of data using `PrinterJob`, but it seems `PrinterJob` prints only `Node`s, so when I use a `TableView` and print it, first it does not print all elements, second I do not like the design. My application already has a functionality of creating pdf tables (a sample is show at the end of this question) and my question is how can I print this pdf, and this proccess of printing is it the same for a POS printer as for a normal printer?

[image]

***EDIT***

Based on the answer of James_D 2, I used this code to print:

```
Document document = createLogDocument(items);
if (document != null) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, byteArrayOutputStream);

    byte[] pdfData = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

    DocFlavor pdfInFormat = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.PDF;

    Doc myDoc = new SimpleDoc(pdfData, pdfInFormat, null);

    PrintRequestAttributeSet set = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();

    PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(pdfInFormat, set);
    if (services.length > 0) {
        PrintService service = ServiceUI.printDialog(null, 50, 50, services, services[0], null, set);


        DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();
        job.print(myDoc, set);

    }
}
} catch (DocumentException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
} catch (PrintException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

as for the `createLogDocument` it's as follows:

```
private static Document createLogDocument(List<Log> logs) throws DocumentException {
Document document = new Document();
document.open();

PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable((new float[]{10, 20, 50, 10, 10}));
table.setWidthPercentage(100);
table.setSpacingAfter(20);
table.setSpacingAfter(20);

PdfPTable header = new PdfPTable((new float[]{10, 20, 50, 10, 10}));
header.setWidthPercentage(100);
header.setSpacingAfter(20);
header.setSpacingBefore(20);

PdfPCell cell = null;

setHeaderCell(cell, "Date", header);
setHeaderCell(cell, "Type", header);
setHeaderCell(cell, "Details", header);
setHeaderCell(cell, "Client", header);
setHeaderCell(cell, "Employee", header);

for (Log log : logs) {

    setNormalCell(cell, log.getDate().toString(), table);

    setNormalCell(cell, log.getDescription().split(":")[0], table);

    setNormalCell(cell, log.getDescription().split(":")[1], table);

    setNormalCell(cell, log.getClient().getName(), table);

    setNormalCell(cell, log.getEmployee().getName(), table);
}

boolean b = true;
for (PdfPRow r : table.getRows()) {
    for (PdfPCell c : r.getCells()) {
        c.setBackgroundColor(b ? BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY : BaseColor.WHITE);
    }
    b = !b;
}

document.add(header);
document.add(table);
document.close();

return document;
```

}

But when I exectue this code I get a `java.io.IOException` saying that `No file in print request`. What mistake am I making?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaFX print API will not be able to print your `TableView` will all the data in it. Recall that table views do not create cells for all of the items in the table: cells are only created for *visible* items (those not scrolled out of the view) and are reused as needed (e.g. when the user scrolls). Since the JavaFX print API prints nodes, and no nodes exist representing all of the data, then this simply won't work.

Since you already have a PDF representation of the data in your table, you can use the standard `javax.print` API to print the PDF. The [package documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/print/package-summary.html) has details on how to do this, but in brief you would do:

```
FileInputStream pdfStream;
try {
   pdfStream = new FileInputStream("file.pdf");
} catch (FileNotFoundException ffne) {
   ffne.printStackTrace();
}
if (pdfStream == null) {
    return;
}

DocFlavor pdfInFormat = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.PDF;
Doc myDoc = new SimpleDoc(pdfStream, pdfInFormat, null);  
PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = 
        new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
PrintService service = 
  PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService(psInFormat, aset);
if (service != null) {
   DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();
   try {
        job.print(myDoc, aset);
   } catch (PrintException pe) {
        pe.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

If your PDF is in memory, rather than in a file, and you can get the data in the form of a `byte[]`, you can do

```
byte[] pdfData = ... ;
DocFlavor pdfInFormat = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.PDF;
Doc myDoc = new SimpleDoc(pdfData, pdfInFormat, null);
```

instead of working with the file as above.

Comment: Will this work for both printers?(I mean POS and normal) since I don't own a POS printer to try it?

Comment: @Ayoub.A I don't own one either... It should. I can really only  refer you to the documentation here. You can get all the printers ("print services") capable of printing a document using `PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(...)`, and query or modify aspects of the printer using `PrintService.getAttributes()` once you have access to the appropriate printer. But I have no way of testing either...

Comment: Could you show me how to show the print dialog I can't find the way to do it. thank you

Comment: @Ayoub.A Did you look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/print/ServiceUI.html

Comment: I take back my comment, I didn't check the documentation.

Comment: I have edited my question would check it to see wheres the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well I changed my `createLog` method to return a byte array, and it seams to work fine.

```
try {
        byte[] pdfData = createLogDocument(items);

        if (pdfData.length != 0) {

            DocFlavor pdfInFormat = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.PDF;

            Doc myDoc = new SimpleDoc(pdfData, pdfInFormat, null);

            PrintRequestAttributeSet set = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();

            PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(pdfInFormat, set);

            if (services.length > 0) {
                PrintService service = ServiceUI.printDialog(null, 50, 50, services, services[0], null, set);

                if (service != null) {
                    DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();
                    job.print(myDoc, set);
                }

            }
        }

    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (PrintException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

As for the `createLogDocument` method:

```
private static byte[] createLogDocument(List<Log> logs) throws DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, byteArrayOutputStream);

    document.open();

    //Fill the document with info

    document.close();
    byte[] pdfData = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

    return pdfData;
}
```